# Is there are any differences between different typename orders in class partial specializatoin definition?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

code shows as below

```
template<typename t1, typename t2, typename t3>
class Test {

};
```

and there are two kinds of partial specializatoin when specify typename t1 as bool

```
// 1
template<typename t5, typename t6>
class Test<bool, t5, t6> {
public:
    t5 n1;
    t6 n2;
};


// 2
template<typename t5, typename t6>
class Test<bool, t6, t5> {
public:
    t5 n1;
    t6 n2;
};
```

It seems that both of them work the same, Is there are any differences between different typename orders in class partial specializatoin definition ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two specializations are different. With `Test<bool, X, Y> t`, specialization (1) will have `t.n1` of type `X`, and specialization (2) will have `t.n1` of type `Y`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3s88Ef)

You can of course fix that easily, by swapping the type parameters you use for `n1` and `n2` at the same time you swap them in the list that follows `Test`. The order of names in the list that follows `template` doesn't matter for a specialization.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for @Igor Tandetnik answer which helps me to figure out how the type go to match, for a class `Test`

```
template<typename t1, typename t2, typename t3>
class Test {

};

template<typename t2, typename t3>
class Test<bool, t3, t2> {   // 1
public:
    t2 n1;
    t3 n2;
};
```

when we define a variable `Test<bool, int, double> t`, it will go to `1` then specify `t3` as `int` and `t2` as `double`